# How to determine if a gif image is touching the mouse-pointer in a tkinter window for python?

Tags: python, tkinter, gif

I'm working on a program using tkinter for python. It is an MIDI file editor. I inserted some gif files into it, but I need the code for them to turn transparent when touching the mousepointer.

I've already asked a similar question, and I got a very helpful result, but it isn't exactly working as expected.

```
def on_mouse_enter(event):
    print("enter...", event.widget)

def on_mouse_leave(event):
    print("leave...", event.widget)

root = tk.Tk()
for i in range(10):
    label = tk.Label(root, text="Item #{}".format(i), name='label-{}'.format(i))
    label.pack()
    label.bind("<Enter>", on_mouse_enter)
    label.bind("<Leave>", on_mouse_leave)

tk.mainloop()
```

I tried replacing `tk.label` with `tk.PhotoImage` but it resulted into an attribute error.

Comment: as for me it works correctly. What means "it isn't exactly working as expected" ? Describe what you get and what you expected. Do it in question (not in comment) so everyone will read it.

Comment: you can't put `PhotoImage` directly in window. You can use `PhotoImage` in `Label(image=...`)` or you can put it on `tk.Canvas` widget - `canvas.create_image((x,y), image=...)`

Comment: See effbot.org: [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm), [Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm)

Comment: If the picture has a transparent background you can just change the background color of the `Label` when `<Enter>` and back to previous color when `<Leave>` , you only see the background color change if you have a picture with transparent background. Also you should first do the research on your own then try it, if it doesn't work then post a question with everything errors , code, images used.

Comment: @furas I get an error. I get a Traceback error. ```Traceback (most recent call last):

_tkinter.TclError: image "..." doesn't exist```I checked the file path, and it existed.  My code is currently this: ```
class image:

    def mode(self, function):

        mode = function
        
    def image_bind(name, x, y, path, function):

        filename=name

        filename = Label(image=path)

        filename.pack(padx = x, pady = y)
        
        filename.bind('<Double-Button-1>', image.mode(function))
        

draw_button = image.image_bind(...)``` What is wrong?

Comment: do you use `PhotoImage` to create image ? `Label` needs `PhotoImage`, not path to image on disk. See [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm).